# Current URL parameter in a new link in the page

Tags: php, get, redirect, url-parameters

I am creating a website for a study for my Ph.D.
I have multiple versions of a same webpage (different colors, different lengths…), and each version has url parameters.

I'd like to create a link at the bottom of each page, which redirects to a questionnaire site, **but automatically retrieving the parameters of the page's url it is on**.

**Example**

Current url is:

> http://abcmessage.com/abc?message=1&color=blue&lenght=small

You click on the link and it takes you to the questionnaire website, keeping the parameters:

> http://questionnaire.com/abc?message=1&color=blue&lenght=small

What should I put next to my redirecting link to do that?

I found that below, but it didn't really work:

```
 $text = '?';
$c = 0;
foreach($_GET as $k => $v){
    $text .= ($c>0) ? "&$k=$v" : "$k=$v";
    $c++;
}
$text = ($text=='?') ? "" : $text;

echo $text;
```

I have to admit I don't know much about php <strike>and Java</strike>, but I'm working on my own and have to get the things done, so I'll learn. So thank you very much to whomever will help :)

Cheers!

Dim

Comment: JAVA is not JavaScript!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [location.seach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location):

```
<a href="#"
onclick="this.href='http://questionnaire.com/abc'+window.location.search">Questionnaire</a>
```

Comment: And that worked like a charm. Thanks a lot @mplungjan!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

It can be done like this:

```
all_requests = $_GET;

$build_query_http = http_build_query($all_requests);

echo "http://questionnaire.com/abc?" . $build_query_http;
```

Or you could even remove all empty requests before passing over:

```
foreach ($all_requests as $key => $var_val) {
  if(empty($var_val) || $var_val=='')
  {
    unset($all_requests[$key]);
  }
}
```

It's worth to look at the [maximum length of a query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string).

Comment: I tried that solution but didn't figure how to implement that code properly. Thanks for your help anyway.